# Problem in updating the HTML table data as the browser crashes when I am getting the data every second using Socket

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sockets, d3.js

I am showing real time data in a HTML table by getting the data from back-end socket developed using Node.js, which sends the data of 200 row (objects) every second which haves some object's value changed.
When I am trying to display or render those data in HTML table, the browser crashes and displays nothing.

I am using Angular and D3 table libraries to do. The code is attached below. Please help me with some ways to fix this or even some better idea to resolved this issue.

**My Component.ts File**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../../Service/http.service';
import { SymbolClass } from 'src/app/Model/Symbol';
import { SocketService } from 'src/app/Service/socket.service';
import { ResponseClass } from 'src/app/Model/Response';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DataSetClass } from 'src/app/Model/DataSet';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BidData } from 'src/app/Model/DataBid';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private symbolList: SymbolClass[];
  private symbolSelected = "XBTUSD";
  private url = 'http://188.166.85.186:7000';
  private socket;
  private dataSetlist: ResponseClass;
  private sub: Subscription;
  private askDept: DataSetClass[];
  private bidDept: BidData[];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private socketService: SocketService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var leftTable = d3.select('#leftTable')
    var rightTable = d3.select('#rightTable')
    leftTable.append('tbody')
    rightTable.append('tbody')

    this.httpService.getSymbol()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.symbolList = data
      this.socketService.emitAfterSymbolChange(this.symbolSelected);
      this.sub = this.socketService.getDataResponse()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.dataSetlist = data
          this.askDept = data.askDepth
          this.setupData(this.askDept,'#leftTable')
          this.bidDept = data.bidDepth
          this.setupData(this.bidDept,'#rightTable')
        });
        
    });

  }
  private dev = function(){
    this.setupData(this.randomizeData(),'#leftTable')
    this.setupData(this.randomizeData(),'#rightTable')
  }

  private setupData = function (data: any,tableType: String) {
    var rows = d3.select(tableType).select('tbody')
      .selectAll('tr')
      .data(data, function (d) {
        return d.title;
      })
    rows.exit().remove()
    var entertd = rows.enter()
      .append('tr')
      .selectAll('td')
      .data(function (d) { 
        return d3.map(d).values();
      })
      .enter()
      .append('td')
      .append('div')
      .append('span')
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      })

    var td = rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function (d) { 
        return d3.map(d).entries();
      })
      .attr('class', function (d) { return d.key })

    td.select('span')
      .text(function (d) {
        if (d.key == 'conversion_rate') {
          return Math.round(100 * d.value) + '%'
        }
        return d.value
      })
  }
}
```

**My component.html file**

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px;">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let sym of symbolList">{{sym}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="row" style="margin:20px 0px;">
    <button (click)="dev()" type="button">Update Data</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-2">
      <div class="chartDoug bg-dark">
        <span class="headTip text-nowrap" style="font-size:20px">Live Order Book!</span>
        <div id="myChart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4 style="text-align:center; color:red;float:left;margin-left:10px;">Volumn:</h4>
        <h4 style="text-align:right; color:red;float:left;margin-left:5px;" class="volumn"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4 style="text-align:center; color:green;float:left;margin-left:10px;">Last Price:</h4>
        <h4 style="text-align:right; color:green;float:left;margin-left:5px;" class="lastprice"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4 style="text-align:center; color:red;float:left;margin-left:10px;">HIGH:</h4>
        <h4 style="text-align:right; color:red;margin-left:5px;float:left;" class="high"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4 style="text-align:center; color:green;float:left;margin-left:10px;">LOW:</h4>
        <h4 style="text-align:right; color:green;margin-left:5px;float:left;" class="low"></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <h2 style="text-align:center; color:green;">BUY</h2>
      <h4 style="text-align:right; color:green;" class="buy_total_amount"></h4>
      <table id="leftTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">No</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Price</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Total Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="text-align: right;" class="buy">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <h2 style="text-align:center; color:red;">SELL</h2>
      <h4 style="text-align:right; color:red;" class="sell_total_amount"></h4>
      <table id="rightTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">No</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Price</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Total Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="text-align: right;" class="sell">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you add a `div` and `span` inside a `td` that only contains a bit of text, why append a `tbody` when it already has one in the html file, what is the function `randomizeData()`, `values()` and `entries()` have arbitrary order

Comment: why don't you use the same `values()` or `entries()` for create and update

Comment: what is the use of the var `entertd`

Comment: div and span is for text decoration. Depending on the td  value which will be a percentage, i will change the color of the span (if 65% then fill 65% of the total length of the span tag, if 90% then fill 90 %)

Comment: i am getting the input from socket, which is a large data, for testing I created a randomize function to simulate the server side giving similar data.

Comment: Thanks, for mentioning about the <tbody>, will remove from the html file. It's redundant.

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say, please share the code if possible. I hope you have understood the problem statement well.

Comment: I want to have an idea what your `data` variable is. How do you make sure you get the `entries` in the order you want, given the 4 column headers, not all columns you want to color the background, removing the `tbody` from the html removes also the style and class

Comment: data contains a array/list of 200 objects, which has 4 class members. Each class member is a number value ranging from 0-100, which I use as a percentage to fill the span tag.

Comment: My problem is that, when I am trying to display the data in table, the browser crashes or sometimes as "Aww snap chrome error comes". I assume that, since the data is changing every second, it is unable to change the value. If I am wrong, please mention.

Comment: It would be good enough, if have worked on similar situation, or have working idea, please share the code.

Comment: that description does not match the column header names, how can "No" or "Quantity" be a percentage, how do you make sure the right number ends in the right column?

Comment: The data which is coming is value ranging from 0-100 for all columns. Those names are needed to be changed. Just reply what is asked. You are going in wrong direction. I am sure about the columns and its not database that if we put something in some other columns it won't work. Have proper idea then say.